# How do I simplify $2^{\sum_{i=1}^n k \,log(i)}$?

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to simplify the following term:
$$2^{\sum_{i=1}^n k \,log(i)}$$
So far I have only been able to come up with the following step:
$$2^{\sum_{i=1}^n k \,log(i)}$$
$$= 2^{\sum_{i=1}^n \,log(i^k)}$$
$$= 2^{\sum_{i=1}^n \,log(i^k)}$$

What else can I do to simplify this term even further?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Try to solve a simpler version at first. E.g.., consider the problem with $k = 1$  Perhaps work it out explicitly for $n = 3$ or $n = 4$. You may even try to pick an particular logarithm, e.g. $\log_2$, and then try to generalize.

Comment: Thanks, using this approach and @Deepak's comment I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: $\log a + \log b = \log ab$

Also, $1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \dots n = n!$

Comment: Oh, I think I can see it now. Is it:
$$2^{k \, log (n!)}$$
?

Comment: @phoebe_albeduddel Yes indeed!